# I am trying to prove the following theorem: Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers. Show that if $x \ne y$ and $x,y \geq 0$, then $x^2 \ne y^2$.

Tags: solution-verification, real-numbers

I am trying to prove the following theorem:

Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers. Show that if $x \ne y$ and $x,y \geq 0$, then $x^2 \ne  y^2$.

---

$Proof.$
The contrapositive of the statement is: If $x^2 =  y^2$, then $x=y$ or $x,y < 0$.
Each real numbers is negative,zero,or positive.
By taking the square root on both sides of the equation $x^2 =  y^2$, one obtains the equations 
$x = y$ for each $x,y \geq 0$ or $-x = -y$ for each $x,y<0$.
By multiplying both sides of the equation $-x = -y$ by $-1$, one obtains the equation $x=y$
Combining all the cases: If $x^2 =  y^2$,then $x = y$, or $x,y<0$, or both $x,y<0$ and $x = y$.
Since each implications and its contrapositive are equivalent, given that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, if $x \ne y$ and $x,y \geq 0$, then $x^2 \ne  y^2$.

---

I need help verifying my proof.

The question is from the book:
Daepp, U., & Gorkin, P. (2011). Reading, writing, and proving: A closer look at mathematics. In *Reading, writing, and proving: A closer look at mathematics* (2nd ed., p. 31). New York: Springer.

Comment: The contrapositive is slightly incorrect. Should end with "then $x=y$ or $x<0$ or $y<0$." Notice that the statement $x,y\geq 0$ is secretly an *and* statement: $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $x^2=y^2$, then $(x-y)(x+y)=0$ and so $x=y$ or $x=-y$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\neq y$ WLOG we can suppose $y=x+a$ with $a>0$, then $y^2=x^2+2\underbrace {ax}_{\ge 0}+\underbrace{a^2}_{>0}>x^2$ so $x^2\neq y^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin.

If $x,y≥0$ and $x≠y$ we have

$$x-y≠0$$ and $$x+y>0$$

Because, $x=y=0$ contradicts with $x≠y$.

Then, we get

$$(x-y)(x+y)≠0$$

$$\implies x^2-y^2≠0$$

$$\implies x^2≠y^2$$